# Assigning and modifying tuples as values for Python Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to create a dictionary using the following code.
        d={}

```
    for item in H:
    if not item[0] in d:
        d[item[0]]=(0,0) 
    d[item[0]][0]+=1
    d[item[0]][1]+=item[1]
```

So basically here, I want a dictionary such that if a key is not in the dictionary, it will equate the value of the key to the tuple (0,0), and then modify the elements of the tuple accordingly ( by adding 1 to the first element of the tuple every time the key appears, and adding item[1], which is an integer, to the second element of the tuple every time the key appears. My code doesn't work as it is. Any ideas as to how this can be fixed?

Thanks,
Junaid

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable so that won't work, ever.  This means you can't modify them after you create them, you need to replace the whole value with a new tuple.

You can use a `defaultdict` to handle the setting of the initial value more elegantly.

I have an inkling a `collections.Counter` is going to be a more suitable data structure for whatever you are trying to achieve here, but you will have to explain your use case a bit more for me to continue...

Answer (score 1):

Python's tuples (like `(0,0)`) are immutable. They can't be updated. You can replace that with `d[item[0]] = [0, 0]` to use a list and have it work.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `tuple` is an immutable data type.

```
In [20]: a = (0,0)

In [21]: a[0]+=1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/xxx/<ipython-input-21-394ba21d2aec> in <module>()
----> 1 a[0]+=1

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

So, you want your values to be a `list`, initialized to `[0,0]`.  Here is a somewhat-more-compact way to do that using `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda:[0,0])
#d['key'][0] += 1
#etc
```